# Rails jQuery add a row from a database table to the last row of a displayed table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to add the last record from a database table into the last row of a html table using jQuery?

Something like this:

```
  $(".save-expense .btn").click ->
    $('#expense_table').append( Expenses.last )
```

And indicate which fields to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news first: **Yes it is possible :)**

What you want is to send an ajax request to your server which returns with the last expenses information. So your javascript should look something like this.

application.js

```
$(".save-expense .btn").live('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/your_controller/last_expense/', # make sure this url is correct
    data: '', # you can also send data if you want
    dataType: "script"
  });
 };
```

And your controller needs to know how to respond to this request, so:

your_controller.rb

```
def last_expense
  # if you send data you can access it via params hash
  # e.g. params[:my_data]
  @last_expense = Expense.last
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js render 'last_record.js.erb'
  end
end
```

the template looks something like:

_last_record.js.erb

```
$('#expense_table').append( <%= j(content) %>)
# or with a partial
$('#expense_table').append( <%= j(render partial: 'expense'), locals: @last_expense %>)
```

PS I'm not sure what you mean with "And indicate which fields to use".
I'm kind of in a hurry so dont trust the syntax (especially the javascript ;))

Hope this helps! will check on it tomorrow again, if you need more help.